# How to make a link on an image in Doxygen

Tags: image, hyperlink, doxygen

I'm writing on a small documentation in Doxygen.

I would like to achieve the following:
On the mainpage a have two links to subpages like "internal Tools" and "external Tools":

```
/**
\mainpage
   
   - \subpage howto_internalTools
   - \subpage howto_externalTools
*/
```

This looks like

[image]

Now I would like to replace the text links with images e.g. like

[image]

But still onclick linking to the `\subpage`s. It seems that this is not provided by the `@image` command..

Is something like that possible and how can I archive this?

Edit I also tried something like:

```
\htmlonly <a href=" \endhtmlonly \subpage internalTools \htmlonly "><img src="image.png" /></a> \endhtmlonly
```

but without luck.